# Does the full 64K get used for every pipe created?

Tags: linux, buffer, pipe

How are pipes implemented re buffering? I might be creating many pipes but only ever sending/receiving a few bytes through them at a time, so don't want to waste memory unnecessarily.

Edit: I understand what buffering is, I am asking how the buffering is implemented in Linux pipes specifically, ie does the full 64K get allocated regardless of highwatermark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buffers are used to equal out the difference in speed between producer and consumer. If you didn't have a buffer, you would have to switch tasks after every byte produced, which would be very inefficient due to the cost of context switches, data and code caches never becoming hot etc. If your consumer can produce data about as fast as the producer consumes it, your buffer use will usually be low (but read on). If the producer is much faster than the consumer, the buffer will fill up completely and the producer will be forced to wait until more space becomes available. The reversed case of slow producer and fast consumer will use a very small part of the buffer for most of the time.

The usage also depends on whether your both processes actually run in parallel (e.g. on separate cores) or if they share a core and only due to the OS's process management are fooled into thinking that they are concurrent. If you have real concurrency (separate core/CPU), your buffer will usually be used less.

Any way, if your applications are not producing much data and their speeds are similar, the buffer will not be very full most of the time. However, I wouldn't be surprised if at OS level, the full 64 kB were allocated any way. But unless you are using an embedded device, 64 kB is not much, so even if always the maximum size is alloctaed, I wouldn't worry about it.

By the way, it is not easy to modify the size of the pipe buffer, for example in [this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe) a number of tricks are suggested but they are actually workarounds which modify the way data from the buffer is consumed, not modifying the actual buffer size. You could check `ulimit -p` but I'm not 100% sure it will give you the control you need.

**EDIT**: Looking at [`fs/pipe.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/pipe.c) and [`include/linux/pipe_fs_i.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/pipe_fs_i.h) in Linux code, it looks like the buffers do change their size. Minimum size of the buffer is a full page, though, so if you only need a few bytes, there will be waste. I'm not sure at this point, but some code that uses `PIPE_DEF_BUFFERS`, which is 16, giving 64 kB with 4 kB pages, makes me wonder if the buffer can fall below 64 kB (the 1 page minimum could be just an additional restriction).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I AM running on an embedded device so 64K per pipe matters. So I need to know specifically whether 64K gets used up regardless of buffer highwatermark.

Comment: @gimmeamilk I did a quick check in Linux source code and added to the answer. You may need to dig a bit deeper into it, but at least we know that the minimum buffer size is at least one page (maybe more), so some waste is unavoidable.

Comment: I was under the impression that the Linux kernel would increase buffer sizes if there is a lot of traffic. Is this not true?

Comment: @MattJoiner I'd say network buffers are different from pipe buffers, in part because with a pipe, both processes are under the control of the same OS instance while on a network connection, usually only one side can be controlled by the OS.